# Django: queryset "loosing" a value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 2 models, one with a list of clients and the other with a list of sales.
My intention is to add sales rank value to the clients queryset.

```
all_clients = Contactos.objects.values("id", "Vendedor", "codigo", 'Nombre', "NombrePcia", "Localidad", "FechaUltVenta")
sales = Ventas.objects.all()
```

Once loaded I aggregate all the sales per client summing the subtotal values of their sales and then order the result by their total sales.

```
sales_client = sales.values('cliente').annotate(
    fact_total=Sum('subtotal'))

client_rank = sales_client .order_by('-fact_total')
```

Then I set the rank of those clients and store the value in a the "Rank" values in the same client_rank queryset.

```
a = 0
for rank in client_rank:
    a = a + 1
    rank['Rank'] = a
```

Everything fine up to now. When I print the results in the template I get the expected values in the "client_rank" queryset: "client name" + "total sales per client" + "Rank".

```
{'cliente': '684 DROGUERIA SUR', 'fact_total': Decimal('846470'), 'Rank': 1}
{'cliente': '699 KINE ESTETIC', 'fact_total': Decimal('418160'), 'Rank': 2}
etc....
```

**The problem starts here**

First we should take into account that not all the clients in the "all_clients" queryset have actual sales in the "sales" queryset. So I must find which ones do have sales, assign them the "Rank" value and a assign a standard value for the ones who don´t.

```
    for subject in all_clients:
    subject_code = str(client["codigo"])
    try:
        selected_subject = ranking_clientes.get(cliente__icontains=subject_code)
        subject ['rank'] = selected_subject['Rank']
    except:
        subject ['rank'] = "Some value"
```

The Try always fails because "selected_subject" doesn´t seems to hace the "Rank" value. If I print the "selected_subject" I get the following:

```
{'cliente': '904 BAHIA BLANCA BASKET', 'fact_total': Decimal('33890')}
```

Any clues on why I´, lossing the "Rank" value? The original "client_rank" queryset still has that value included.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `all_clients` and how does it relate to `client_rank`?

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman You can see that at the beggining of my explanation. "All clients" is the queryset with the list of clients and "client_rank" comes from the "Sales" queryset. Both have a field with the client names. There is no ForeignFiled relating them directly, that is why I should compare the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that `ranking_clientes` is the same as `client_rank`.

The problem is that `.get` will always do a new query against the database. This means that any modifications you made to the dictionaries returned in the original query will not have been applied to the result of the `get` call.

You would need to iterate through your query to find the one you need:

```
selected_subject = next(client for client in ranking_clientes if subject_code in client.cliente)
```

Note, this is pretty inefficient if you have a lot of clients. I would rethink your model structure. Alternatively, you could look into using a [database function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#window-functions) to return the rank directly as part of the original query.

Comment: Thanks  @DanielRoseman  . That explains it. I´ll investigate the database functions option as I can´t change the original models´ structure.